# CoreData - Getting entries that do not exist in another table

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

Given two tables:

```
Data - Contains raw data, per value per day.
-----------
Value | Price | Date | DataType (string)
```

Data may contain:

```
Units | Price | Date          | DataType
---------------------------------
10    | 0.99  | March 1, 2014 | "1A"
20    | 0.99  | March 1, 2014 | "1B"
4     | 0.99  | March 1, 2014 | "2"
```

And may have hundreds of thousands of records.

Normally to query `Data` I would use a predicate such as (uses [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)):

```
NSArray * results = [Data MR_findAllWithPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"date > x AND date < y AND dataType IN ('1A', '1B')"]];

// Calculate sums per day.
// .... Loops through results, units * price summed per day.
```

But with a large amount of rows, this is getting very slow.

There are a few things that I have tried to get this quicker.

1. Sum via `NSExpression`. Unfortunately this does not work due to the need of using a `multiple:by` expression. ([Fetch aggregate data from NSManagedObject using another expression as argument to sum: expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879025/fetch-aggregate-data-from-nsmanagedobject-using-another-expression-as-argument-t) for more details).
2. Now my thoughts are to create a cached table. I'm attempting to use a structure like the following:

```
CachedData
-----------
Sum | Date | CacheType (integer)
```

Which I have created and tested inserting data into and it seems to be much faster (some of my calculations went from ~7 seconds to ~0.5s). But the problem is creating this cache table via core data.

If I was using raw SQLite I could do something similar to:

```
INSERT INTO CachedData
  (CacheType, Sum, Date)

SELECT
  0,
  (Value * Price),
  Date
FROM
  Data
WHERE
  DataType IN ('1A', '1B') AND
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CachedData WHERE CacheType = 0 AND CachedData.Date = Data.Date);
```

Then anytime data had new inserts (never updates, just inserts), I could run this query quickly, having it only update my new data.

In coredata on the other hand, I can't seem to figure out a nice way to do this, other than selecting ALL of the uncached data, selecting all of the cached data and doing a few for loops to do comparisons on existence, then inserting. While this works, it is SLOOOOOOOOW (vs the sqlite query which can be done in seconds).

While thinking about this, I think a simple way would be to add a `cached` bool column to my data table. Then at least in my enumeration loop I can do a predicate on that column. I'm still interested to know if there is a way to do this via coredata without adding an extra column though.

**TL;DR**

Is there a way I can get all the records for one table that do NOT exists in another table? Possibly through an `NSPredicate` subquery?

Answer (score 1):

First, with your original desire, did you set your attributes to be indexed?  This has some overhead for inserts, but will really speed up access like you want.

Second, why run a query when data is inserted.  You could easily catch the `DidSave` notification from the MOC, and do what you want for a newly inserted object, which would include adding into another store.  Or, you could use a `NSFetchedResultsController` and just implement its delegate... which will provide a similar result of watching what's happening in a managed object context... with a probably more familiar API.  You don't have to use a FRC with a TableView...